# SwiftUI Canvas is blank or has crashed?

Tags: swiftui

My SwiftUI Canvas has disappeared. Has it crashed? I don't see any output in the console.

I have macOS 10.15 Catalina (the requirement for SwiftUI) and Xcode 11+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

If your SwiftUI view were named "TestView," the following would be necessary to display the Canvas:

```
#if DEBUG
struct TestView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Simply copy the above code and change the instances of "TestView" to whatever your file is called. Click "Resume" and the canvas should load up.

**Solution 2**

If the above did not work, try to clear the derived data from the machine by first closing Xcode, then navigating in Finder to

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Drag all of the files to the trash and restart Xcode. Don't worry, none of your code will be deleted, this is just the data that Xcode creates to help it to compile your project faster.